# Want the data of Upline and Downline for particular ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

here is the table 
and data like:

```
id name
1  test1
2  test2
3  test3
4  test4
5  test5
6  test6
```

From above data i want the data like 
if i pass the id as parameter and return the data from from up and gown by order

Example if i pass the id as parameter = 4 then it should be return 
upline 2 row and downline 2 row for particular id, and it should be like this

```
id name

2  test2
3  test3
4  test4
5  test5
6  test6
```

and same for the id = 3

```
id name
1  test1
2  test2
3  test3
4  test4
5  test5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT TOP 3 id, name
    FROM table
    WHERE id =< @id 
    ORDER BY id DESC

```
UNION 

SELECT TOP 2 id, name
FROM table
WHERE id > @id 
ORDER BY id ACS
```

Comment: Assuming `id` is a primary key, probably best to use `UNION ALL` here.

Comment: Hello, I have tried with above script. because Union and order by is not working together.

Comment: So can you provide me alternative solution

Comment: Yes my mistake i just wrote that by hand i did not test it here are two alternatives 

SELECT *
FROM 
(
 SELECT TOP 3 id, name
        FROM table
        WHERE id =< @id 
        ORDER BY id DESC

) x

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM 
(
 SELECT TOP 2 id, name
        FROM table
        WHERE id > @id 
        ORDER BY id ACS
) x

Second alternative

SELECT TOP 3 id, name
INTO #tmp
FROM table
WHERE id =< @id 
ORDER BY id DESC

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT TOP 2 id, name
FROM table
WHERE id > @id 
ORDER BY id ACS

SELECT * FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp